# SPFx v1.5 building Extension and WebPart as single solution

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

I recently updated my SPFx framework to v1.5.0 and I wanted to create a solution that has both Extensions (Application Customizer) and Client Side Webparts. Now if I try creating a WebPart first and then try adding an Extension with
(yo @microsoft/sharepoint), I get prompted asking :

**Add a new Web Part to solution ###### 

?What is your Web part name ?** 
The same thing applies for Extensions as well.
My ask is has MS removed the ability to add both Extensions and WebParts to single solution ? 
 Any pointers is/are welcome...

Comment: MS has identified this as a bug, [link](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1991). More updates to follow this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed a bug with `SPFx v 1.5`.

It was fixed with recently released `SPFx 1.5.1`. Simply update your yeoman generator and recreate the projects using the below commandlet:

`npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@latest -g`

Reference - [SPFx v1.5.1 Release notes](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Release-Notes-for-SPFx-Package-Version-1.5.1)